# 'The bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable' error during laravel 6 testing

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-6

Laravel 6 includes some additional configuration in phpunit.xml:

```
<server name="APP_CONFIG_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/config.phpunit.php"/>
<server name="APP_SERVICES_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/services.phpunit.php"/>
<server name="APP_PACKAGES_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/packages.phpunit.php"/>
<server name="APP_ROUTES_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/routes.phpunit.php"/>
<server name="APP_EVENTS_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/events.phpunit.php"/>
```

If I run the tests in PHPStorm, I get the following error:

> In PackageManifest.php line 168:
>
> The bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable.

But the bootstrap/cache directory is indeed present and writable. However, if I comment out those new configs in phpunit.xml, my tests run without any errors. How do I fix this?

I also ran `php artisan cache:clear`. No luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up file permissions for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel)

Comment: @Script47 No. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue from Laravel end:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/29862

[This PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/29890) Fixes that issue.

Updating the framework version to the latest version (6.0.3 as of the time of this answer) fixes the problem.

Answer (score 7):

If you're running Linux, most likely it's a read/write permission problem, to solve these problems, do the following:

***Before doing the steps below, be sure to be outside of your Laravel folder***

Assuming that your `user` should be the owner, type the following command:

```
sudo chown -R user:www-data /path/of/your/laravel/project
```

Then give the user and webserver permissions as follows:

```
sudo find /path/of/your/laravel/project -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

then run:

```
sudo find /path/of/your/laravel/project -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

After you run those commands, go to your Laravel folder and give the webserver rights to read/write to your `bootstrap/cache` and `storage` folder:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

It should solve not only your problem but also solves your project security.

Comment: This is an answer you want to read. Simple and straight forward.